# Tensoflow 2.0 Exporting and Importing metagraphs is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, seq2seq

("Exporting/importing meta graphs is not supported when "
RuntimeError: Exporting/importing meta graphs is not supported when eager execution is enabled. No graph exists when eager execution is enabled.

I am trying to run this below code in tensorflow in version 2.7 but getting above error

```
loaded_graph = tf.Graph()
sess=tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()
save_path = './'+model_dir+'/'+save_path
loader = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(save_path + '.meta')
loader.restore(sess, save_path)
```

Any suggestion here?

Comment: As error shows, Graph mode execution can be supported only in `Tensorflow 1.x` not in `Tensorflow 2.x` which also calls eager mode. However you can run this code by enabling  `Tensorflow 1.x`  using `%tensorflow_version 1.x`, then `import tensorflow as tf`. Let us know if issue still persists.